# MD5 to UTF8 string encoding wrong characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, md5

I need to transform the string

`NSString * password = @"."`

in this string

**PXñ¯ƒˆc?`œ­·ZuÜ**

passing trough an MD5 conversion.

Using this `NSString` category

```
- (NSString *)MD5
{
    const char *cString = [self UTF8String];
    unsigned char hashBuffer[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CC_MD5(cString, (unsigned int)strlen(cString), hashBuffer);

    NSMutableString *hash = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        [hash appendFormat:@"%02x",hashBuffer[i]];
    }

    NSString *string = [hash uppercaseString];
    NSMutableString * newString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; //will contain your result-string
    int i = 0;
    while (i < [string length])
    {
        NSString * hexChar = [string substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(i, 2)];
        int value = 0;
        sscanf([hexChar cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], "%x", &value);
        [newString appendFormat:@"%c", (char)value];
        i+=2;
    }

    return newString;
}
```

I obtain this string

**PXñ¯c?`­·ZuÜ**

instead

**PXñ¯ƒˆc?`œ­·ZuÜ**

The strings are slightly different but the first doesn't have **ƒˆ** and **œ** characters.
Ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

The character "œ" (LATIN SMALL LIGATURE OE U+0153) is encoded in UTF-8 as `c5 93`, it needs two bytes to be represented so your while loop will have trouble with it.

I would suggest trying to convert the data in a more direct manner, along the lines of:

```
- (NSString *)MD5
{
    const char *cString = [self UTF8String];
    unsigned char hashBuffer[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CC_MD5(cString, (unsigned int)strlen(cString), hashBuffer);

    NSString * newString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:hashBuffer
                                                    length:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return newString;
}
```

However, I feel there is a problem with your scheme, because I don't see how you will encode MD5s that contain null bytes (0x00) ?

Comment: I just tested the sample code I've written and I can't make it work, I think your MD5 might give invalid UTF8 characters. How did you get the first encoding you copied in your question?

Comment: It's the string that server wants back. Taken from server code in .NET.

Comment: I think your encoding might be CP-1252 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) instead (possibly converted into UTF8?). You still need to figure out how bytes 0x00-0x1F are dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

Your scheme is hopelessly flawed. Your MD5 digest is an arbitrary sequence of bytes. Trying to convert an arbitrary byte sequence to a string is doomed from the start. Most arbitrary byte sequences are *not* valid UTF-8. Not only sequences containing nul bytes, but most sequences containing characters that don't happen to be in the ASCII range.

I'd suggest changing the method to return an NSData object, like

return [NSData dataWithBytes:hashBuffer length:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];